# CSS Gallery image box size change

Tags: html, css, grid

I've been trying to create two column layout image gallery but the problem is
When I try to change image box size(in which the image is containing) the layout goes to single column but i want it to be two column. Please help. Given below my code snippet.

If any other ways are possible to build this layout please mention below it would be good.

[Code Snippet](https://codepen.io/Codehunt/pen/ZJLbmj)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico');
.xop-section {
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 6% 2%;

}

.xop-grid {
 margin: 20px 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

.xop-grid:after {
 clear: both;
}

.xop-grid:after,
.xop-box:before {
 content: '';
 display: table;
}

.xop-grid li {
 width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 20px;
}

.xop-box {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out, ;
}

.xop-box:hover {
 transform: scale(1.05);
}

.xop-img-1 {
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10)), /* bottom, image */
 url(../images/soap.jpg);
}

.xop-img-2 {
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10)), /* bottom, image */
 url(../images/soap.jpg);
}

.xop-img-3 {
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10)), /* bottom, image */
 url(../images/flower.jpg);
}

.xop-img-4 {
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10)), /* bottom, image */
 url(../images/feather.jpg);
}

.xop-img-5 {
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10)), /* bottom, image */
 url(../images/feather.jpg);
}

.xop-img-6 {
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10)), /* bottom, image */
 url(../images/feather.jpg);
}

.xop-info {
 position: absolute;
 width: inherit;
 height: inherit;
}

.xop-info h3 {
 font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 42px;
 margin: 0 30px;
 padding: 100px 0 0 0;
 line-height: 1.5;
}

.xop-info p {
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 4px 5px;
 margin: 0 30px;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="xop-section">
  <ul class="xop-grid">
   <li>
    <div class="xop-box xop-img-1">
     <a href="#">
      <div class="xop-info">
       <h3>Paint</h3>
       <p>Nulla commodo iaculis vulputate. Nullam enim mauris, dignissim id est nec, mollis pretium nulla.</p>
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="xop-box xop-img-2">
     <a href="#">
      <div class="xop-info">
       <h3>Soap</h3>
       <p>Nulla commodo iaculis vulputate. Nullam enim mauris, dignissim id est nec, mollis pretium nulla.</p>
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="xop-box xop-img-3">
     <a href="#">
      <div class="xop-info">
       <h3>Flowers</h3>
       <p>Nulla commodo iaculis vulputate. Nullam enim mauris, dignissim id est nec, mollis pretium nulla.</p>
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="xop-box xop-img-4">
     <a href="#">
      <div class="xop-info">
       <h3>Feathers</h3>
       <p>Nulla commodo iaculis vulputate. Nullam enim mauris, dignissim id est nec, mollis pretium nulla.</p>
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="xop-box xop-img-5">
     <a href="#">
      <div class="xop-info">
       <h3>Feathers</h3>
       <p>Nulla commodo iaculis vulputate. Nullam enim mauris, dignissim id est nec, mollis pretium nulla.</p>
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="xop-box xop-img-6">
     <a href="#">
      <div class="xop-info">
       <h3>Feathers</h3>
       <p>Nulla commodo iaculis vulputate. Nullam enim mauris, dignissim id est nec, mollis pretium nulla.</p>
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flexbox in your project instead of display 'block' property. It use help you create multiple column layout with same column width.

```
.xop-grid {
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
;}
```

Comment: Thanks but can you show me the code snippet of using flexbox method of two column gallery.

Comment: Ok. Give me some time

Comment: Sure. waiting to see the flexbox version.

Comment: Great. but it should be responsive that in desktops and tablets only two column layout and in mobile phones it is to be single column layout. ? How

Comment: using flexbox great feature is responsive design easy. when you resize your windows please decrease your  grid item width as mush you can made two column. Ex: your tablet window is 800 or something you need to decease your grid item size smaller then 400 that made you two column grid. hope you understand or any query please ask. thanks

Comment: Thanks it worked. but the image inside box is not 100% width it need to be ? Any idea

Answer (score 0):

Your css:
For xop-section you specified a 
max-width:960px;

Then later in 
Xop-grid-li: 300px;

I was able to resolve by changing the max-width to 1700px;
And I could change the xop-grid-li values to fit, I don't know if this is desired behavior or not.

By the way, why not take the div tags out of your li tags? If you don't need the image to change on:hover but just need a transparency/darken change you could place an image there and add an rgba hover.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9W3O.jpg

Answer (score 0):

When I pulled your coding into dreamweaver I had to change the size of .xop-grid li to 440px and added a float left in order to achieve what you needed. I hope this helps you, maybe there is a better solution.

```
.xop-grid li {
    width: 440px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    float:left;
}
```

[image]